# if I want to make a tree structure from the string?

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

Let say I have a  node with

```
[[5,3],[11,5],[13,3],[3,5],[6,1],[1,3],[8,6],[7,2],[2,2]]
```

and want to make a tree structure like

[image]

```
    class Tree:
        def __init__(self):
            self.parent =None
            self.left = None
            self.right = None
            self.data = None

for i in lst:
    print(i)
    if root==None:
        root = Tree()
        root.data = i
    else:
        if root.left == None or root.right==None:
            if root.data[0] < l[0]: root.right = l
            else: root.left = l
        else:
```

I stuck in here to construct the tree structure with list
or is there a better or efficient way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your list contains coordinates of the nodes. And the edges between nodes are constructed based on their spatial positions. In such case taking the very first node in the list as a root of the entire tree (as your algorithm does) is a too bold decision.

I'm not sure would it be the most efficient (from the runtime complexity standpoint) way to solve the problem, but I would start by sorting the list by the Y coordinate. The reasoning is simple - nodes in a rooted tree are always layered. Thus, the root node must have the highest Y coordinate. Once you found a root node (which is a very first node in the sorted list), proceed to the next layer. And the decision whether the next node in the list should be a left or a right child of the current node will be based on its X coordinate. And then recurse for the left and right subtrees.

Answer (score -1):

Your input does not provide nodes that match your desired tree structure, however, I have provided corrected input with a possible solution:

```
data = [[7, 2], [2, 3], [7, 4], [4, 6], [4, 1], [6, 9], [1, 8], [8, 5]]
class Tree:
  def __init__(self, _val, _children):
     self.val, self.children = _val, list(map(self.__class__.to_tree, _children))
  @classmethod
  def to_tree(cls, _p = [a for a, b in data if all(c != a for _, c in data)][0]):
    return cls(_p, [b for a, b in data if a == _p])
  def __repr__(self):
    return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.val}, {self.children}))'

t = Tree.to_tree()
```

Output:

```
Tree(7, [Tree(2, [Tree(3, []))])), Tree(4, [Tree(6, [Tree(9, []))])), Tree(1, [Tree(8, [Tree(5, []))]))]))]))]))
```

Comment: my input and picture is a match, isn't it?

Comment: @jake I cannot find the values `13` or `11` in any of the nodes of your picture. Can you clarify?